# Insert numeric data from R into Teradata database fails when sending to many rows

Tags: r, teradata, dbi, dbplyr

Inserting data from a dataframe in R into a predefined table on Teradata database works fine and is quite fast for small (few rows) dataframes. However I discovered a strange behaviour when inserting to many numeric values. insert process fails with error:

> Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) :
>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1791: HY104: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
>   Invalid precision: cbColDef value out of range

Here is a small reprex:

```
/* Teradata database - creating table */
create table upload_test (
    ID      INTEGER,
    val     DECIMAL(8,4)
);
```

Inserting a small dataframe works fine:

```
# R creating dataframe and send it to db
up_test1k = tibble(ID=1:1000, val=0.1234)

con = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...)
dbplyr::db_insert_into(con, "upload_test", up_test1k)
```

Inserting a dataframe with 2000 rows fails:

```
up_test2k = tibble(ID=1:2000, val=0.1234)
dbplyr::db_insert_into(con, "upload_test", up_test2k)

Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
 nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1791: HY104: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Invalid 
 precision: cbColDef value out of range
```

Same behaviour (1000 rows ok, 2000 rows fail) with

- using different function: DBI::dbWriteTable(..., append=TRUE)
- changing column definition to DECIMAL(18,8)
- defining val as.character() in dataframe

Inserting larger dataframes (> 10'000 rows) containing just integers and characters works fine.

---

System information:

- R.Version()$version.string "R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)"
- packageVersion("odbc") ‘1.1.6’
- packageVersion("DBI") ‘1.0.0’
- packageVersion("dbplyr") ‘1.3.0’
- select * from dbc.dbcinfo; VERSION  15.10.07.04

Comment: Are you on SQLServer? You might want to add the server-specific tag. Also teradata released a package that you might want to try.

Comment: @Elin, Thank you for your input, Teradata runs on some *nix machines whereas my R instance runs on Win10, but I don't think that's relevant for this case.
can you specify "Also teradata released a package"?

Comment: The reason I asked is that if you google your message you will see that there are quite a few results,did you try any of the suggestions? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr.teradata/index.html